# submitting form with jQuery/AJAX, cant stop page from refreshing on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having trouble getting my `AJAX` form to `POST` to my PHP Script without refreshing the page.

I have added `e.preventDefault()` both before and after the AJAX request but it doesn't appear to have any affect, which seems strange.

Here's my javascript:

```
// AJAX form submit
$("form[name=signoutRequestForm]").on("submit", function(e){

    var cval = confirm.val().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    if( cval !== "yes"  ) {
        alert("You must accept the borrowing policy.");
    }else{
        var formData = {
            validForm: true,
            name_txt: name.val(),
            productName_sel: prodName.val(),
            signoutDateStart_txt: startDate.val(),
            signoutDateEnd_txt: returnDate.val(),
            additionalNotes_txtarea: addNotes.val(),
            disclaimer_txt: confirm.val(),
            recaptcha_challenge_field: recap_challenge.val(),
            recaptcha_response_field: recap_response.val(),
            studentUse: studentUse.val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            ulr: confLocation,
            data: formData,
            done: function(data){
                $(".signoutRequestForm").remove();
                $(".signout-form-container").html( data );
            }
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Right now, when I hit submit, the page just appears to refresh without the form ever actually submitting.

Comment: Is `ulr: confLocation` present in your real code?

Comment: instead of `.on("submit",..)` try `.on("click",..)`

Comment: @JasonP: yes it's a string elsewhere in my code, pointing to the PHP script I'm posting to.

Comment: @AmitSoni that won't work, this is a form not a button.

Comment: @Prefix `ulr` should be `url`.

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error? If there's an error, the javascript will not be able to prevent the form from being submitted.  Have you checked your console?

Comment: @JasonP: holy cow, that's embarrassing -- how I didn't see that is beyond me, haha.

Comment: @Prefix It happens. Does that fix your issue?

Comment: If this anonymous function is crashing anywhere, then it won't make it to the `e.preventDefault()` call. Try putting that at the top.

Comment: i never seen this "done: function(data)" in $.ajax

Comment: @AlexMorrise: I moved it to the top of the function, however the page still appears to be refreshing.

Comment: @PankajSharma is right, it should be "success" or a `.done()` chained at the end

Comment: @Prefix If the page is still refreshing, even with that line at the top, it indicates to me that the line isn't being reached. Have you checked your javascript console for errors?

Comment: @JasonP may be on the right track. It could be that this binding isn't occurring when the form exists on the page, or perhaps that the actual form name doesn't match what's in your script.

Comment: Are you calling the code in a DOM ready handler so that the form actually exists at the time you try to bind event handlers to it?

Comment: @PankajSharma - changed it to `success`, still refreshing

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: this is all occurring inside of a `$(function() {}` (shorthand for document ready)

Comment: You could try adding an `alert` or a `console.log` right at the top of the function and see if it happens. If it doesn't then you aren't reaching this script at all.

Comment: @AlexMorrise: just realized the `.on("submit")` line is throwing the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` -- why is this undefined? o_O

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, it could be a `$` conflict. What happens if you write `jQuery("form...")` instead of `$("form...")`?

Comment: Or you could try writing `;$("form...")` in case the previous script didn't end in a semi-colon.

Comment: @AlexMorrise: tried both, neither fixes the `undefined is not a function` error... NO idea what I'm doing wrong here :\

Comment: Are you certain you're including jQuery? If so, which version are you including?

Comment: @AlexMorrise: yup, positive. Unfortunately it's an older version (1.5.2) but is used prominently throughout the site for various features. jQuery UI 1.8.11 is also being used

Comment: `.on()` was added in 1.7. For versions prior to that, use `.bind()`.

Comment: @JasonP: THAT was it!! Thank you! Post an answer so I can accept. Lots of great advice in here, wish I could accept more than 1.

Comment: @JasonP, thanks. That's what I was getting at. Definitely post an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it was determined that the call to `.on()` was resulting in an exception (`TypeError: undefined is not a function`) and that you are using jQuery v1.5.2.

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was not added until version 1.7. For older versions, `.bind()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

just use `return false`

```
    .....
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
});
```

Comment: interesting, why does it require return false? I thought e.preventDefault() was all that was needed to prevent the default behavior of a form.

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @Prefix It is for sure. Then i'm not sure why this answer has been upvoted?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Why doesn't e.preventDefault() work though? I thought that's what it was for.

Comment: `return false` is deprecated in modern browsers

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @da_berni Well, any ref on that? How can it be 'deprecated'?! EDIT: but anyway, this answer won't fix OP's issue

Comment: @A.Wolff, it is or will be deprecated in jQuery, as far as I know. jQuery has to manually check if the function returns false and then stop propagation and prevent default, but they're taking that check out.

Comment: @AlexMorrise Ok but then where do you read it? First time i heard jQuery will no more handle `return false;` as a shorthand for stopping propagation and preventing default. And anyway, not related to browser and would be calling for major issue regarding older code backward compatibility